# mutate_at(): must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
df <- tibble(a = rnorm(10,0,1), b = a+6, c = b/2)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(a, b), scale) %>% GGally::ggpairs()
```

This returned the error

> Error: Column `a` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Some further digging showed that the `str()` is changed with `mutate_at()`.

```
> df %>% mutate_at(vars(a, b), scale) %>% str
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num [1:10, 1] -1.274 -0.81 0.362 1.374 1.06 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 0.106
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.813
 $ b: num [1:10, 1] -1.274 -0.81 0.362 1.374 1.06 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 6.11
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 0.813
 $ c: num  2.54 2.72 3.2 3.61 3.48 ...
```

How do I work with `df` after I changed variables via `mutate_at()`? For example, how can I use `GGally::ggcoef` with my scaled data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `scale()` function adds extra attributes to your vector so it's possible to un-scale your vector later. But this seems to trick `ggpairs` into not thinking it's a numeric vector. You can make your own wrapper to clean up the extra attributes

```
simple_scale <- function(...) as.numeric(scale(...))
```

Then you can just do

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(a, b), simple_scale) %>% GGally::ggpairs()
```